# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS except when it comes from a specific referrer

Tags: nginx

I have a http service that must be used by my web application during production and development. I would like to redirect all `http` traffic on this service to `https` unless the request comes from the `lvh.me:9292` referrer (which is the URL we use during development). My naive approach was a `map` as follows:

```
map "$scheme:$http_referrer" $redirect_https {                                                        
    ~/^https/            0;                                                                           
    ~/.*lvh\.me:9292.*/  0;                                                                           
    default              1;                                                                           
}
```

In my understand this should simply concatenate the `$scheme` and the `$http_referrer` and will then match against the (crude) expressions that I defined. The redirect is then written as follows:

```
if ($redirect_http = 1) {                                                                           
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                          
}
```

This however *always* results in an endless redirection cycle no matter what URL I request (with or without https, with our without a matching referrer). Am I misunderstanding something essential? Are my dumbed down regexes incorrect? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: Do you actually mean the referrer (which is often missing, especially when you start mixing http and https), or do you mean the host? Or, if you are talking about a webservice on one server queried from pages served from another host?

Comment: You should remove the `/`s from your regular expressions. That is not the correct syntax. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question for the full nginx configuration.